# wifi hotspot usage tracking

Tags: wireless

iam using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and i enabled wifi hotspot.4 devices are connected to it.how can i know how much data they  have used and  in how much speed bandwidth is distributing among all clients?

Answer (score 0):

For how much data each uses, you can use *[darkstat](https://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/)* --

`sudo apt-get install darkstat`. You will have to edit the config file `/etc/darkstat/init.cfg` to match your system specification.